# Mean value theorem of a differentiable function $f$ in $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let , $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $f(a+)$ and $f(b-)$ exists. Then which are correct?

(A) There exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(b-)-f(a+)=(b-a)f'(c)$.

(B) There exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(b-)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$.

(C) There exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a+)=(b-a)f'(c)$.

(D) There exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$.

As , $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f(a+)$ and $f(b-)$ exists so by Mean-Value-Theorem , option (D) is correct.

But what about the other options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point of the question is that $f(x)$ may **not** be continuous at $a$ or $b$. So the best answer is $(A)$. The reason is that the existence of these limits

$$\eqalign{
  & f(a + ) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a + } f(x)  \cr 
  & f(b + ) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to b + } f(x) \cr} $$

does **not** guaarantee that $f(x)$ is defined at $a$ or $b$ or being continuous there. For example, consider the following

$$f(x) = \left\{ {\matrix{
   0 \hfill & {x = a} \hfill  \cr 
   {{x^2}} \hfill & {x \ne a,b} \hfill  \cr 
   0 \hfill & {x = b} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.$$

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: Do you agree with my answer? :)